# OpenJDK built in Ubuntu 12.10, but not working?

Tags: 12.10, java, openjdk

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10, and I just now realized I haven't installed Java on it.

When I was going to, I saw that I already have java installed.

`java -version` gives me:

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.7) (7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.10)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Yet I can't see any applets in Firefox. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you explain what is not working? Or do you want the java from oracle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the JRE installed, but not the browser plug-in.

You will need to install [icedtea-7-plugin [image: Install icedtea-7-plugin]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/icedtea-7-plugin) to be able to use Java applets in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Java**

You might want to install Oracle Java 7 anyway, because applets can be a bit nitpicky about the versions (often requiring the Oracle version). Oracle Java and OpenJDK can co-exist - you do not have to uninstall the other one.

In the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Use this command to select which one you want to enable:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: Does this also install the browser plugin?

Comment: @gertvdijk Yes.